# Updating DataFrame globally from Dash callback

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I'm developing a dash app with graphs, sliders, dropdowns, and tables. I feel it is an easy yet efficient framework + library to design interactive web apps (dashboards).

I came across a use case where I need to update the DataFrame based on the input from the dropdown. After digging the internet for a couple of days somehow I managed to do that (in an appropriate way).

I believe that there will be a simple way to achieve my requirement than the one I'm following right now.

This is the sample code that reflects my approach

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

df1 = pd.read_csv('dataset1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dataset2.csv')
final_df=[df1,df2]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(id='container',children=[
 dcc.Dropdown(
            id='user',
            options=[{'label': 'User 1','value': 'u1'},
                     {'label': 'User 2','value': 'u2'},
                     {'label': 'User 3','value': 'u3'}],
            value='u1',
        ),
 dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
 ])

@app.callback(
     Output('graph', 'figure'),
     [Input('user', 'value')])
def update_graph_1(user_value) :
    if user_value == 'u1':
       df = final_df[0]
       fig = (px.line(df, x='col1',y='col2').update_traces(mode='lines+markers'))
       return fig
    elif user_value == 'u2' :
       df = final_df[1]
       fig = (px.line(df, x='col1',y='col2').update_traces(mode='lines+markers'))
       return fig
    elif user_value == 'u3' :
       df = final_df[3]
       fig = (px.line(df, x='col1',y='col2').update_traces(mode='lines+markers'))
       return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

By following the above approach I can able to get the desired result for now. But, I believe this is not the proper way to sort my requirement.

**Expected Output:** Once the page is loaded, when I go ahead and select the user from the dropdown menu then the respected dataframe should load into the "df". For example, if I select 'User 1' then "df" should update with the DataSet-1. Respectively if I select 'User 2 then "df" should update with the DataSet-1 and the data points in "graph" should update according to the dataset loaded into "df".

I hope my question is clear and any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question, and add expected output and sample data?

Comment: @Malo, appreciate your interest in helping me out with this. I've edited the question with expected output format. Hope it is clear now for understanding my requirement.